# Struct expression parameter vs. type parameter

Tags: d

I'm making an input range to iterate over a custom container that holds data points that need to remain accurately paired as inputs and targets. I need different Ranges for returning training data (double[][]), inputs (double[]) and the targets (also double[]). I managed to get the following code to compile and work perfectly, but I don't know why.

```
public struct DataRange(string type) 
if( type == "TrainingData" || 
type == "InputData"    ||
type == "TargetData" )
{

  private immutable(int) length;
  private uint next;
  private Data data;

  this(Data d){
    this.length = d.numPoints;
    this.next = 0;
    this.data = d;
  }

  @property bool empty(){return next == length;}

  @property auto front(){
    static if(type == "TrainingData")
      return this.data.getTrainingData(next);
    else static if(type == "InputData")
      return this.data.getInputData(next);
    else return this.data.getTargetData(next);
  }

   void popFront(){++next;}
}
static assert(isInputRange!(DataRange!"TrainingData"));
static assert(isInputRange!(DataRange!"InputData"));
static assert(isInputRange!(DataRange!"TargetData"));
```

I've been reading the "The D Programming Language" by Alexandrescu, and I have found parameterized structs of the form

```
struct S(T){...} // or
struct S(T[]){...}
```

but these take type parameters, not expressions like I've done. I haven't been able to find any similar examples on [dlang.org](http://dlang.org) with parameterized types.

This compiles and works on DMD 2.066 and GDC 4.9.0.

I don't even know why I tried this, and looking back at it I don't know why it works. Anybody know what I'm missing? Where is this documented?

Comment: There is a useful book/tutorial on templates in D available online: https://github.com/PhilippeSigaud/D-templates-tutorial. It can explain things better than the language documentation sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could use an enum to simplify the constraint in such a way that a wrong template instantiation is impossible (even if in your code the template constraint does it perfectly). example:

```
enum rangeKind{training, input, target};
public struct DataRange(rangeKind Kind)
{
}

void main(string args[])
{
    DataRange!(rangeKind.training) dr;
}
```

Comment: That's great too, I like that better actually. It's a lot more succinct, and reusable. The strings seemed a little hokey. But this can be re-used, for instance there are other areas where I will want to differentiate between which part of the data I want to deal with, again with a lot of reusable code. I can just use this enum there again instead of re-creating the strings and exact same template constraints again.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the answer. Though this wasn't specifically mentioned or described in any of the tutorials or anywhere in the book, I was eventually able to find it at [http://dlang.org.template.html](http://dlang.org/template.html). Basically there are two things going on here.

1.) Though my code says struct, this is really a template (that results in a struct). I have seen examples of this online and in the book, though it wasn't described as a template. It was a bit confusing because I didn't use the template keyword, and in the book they are described as "parameterized."

2.) From the website linked above...

> Template parameters can be types, values, symbols, or tuples

So in my case my template parameter was a symbol. The examples in the book used types.

Digging into the language specifications on the website reveals there is a lot more going on than is covered in the book!